# Use google maps with requirejs and asyncjs plugin does not work with paths alias name

Tags: google-maps, requirejs

In my Viewmodel I inject google this way with requirejs and the async plugin of requirejs:

```
define(['async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false!callback'], function(){

//Google maps is available and all components are ready to use.

}
```

this is hardcoded. That way I can not run unit tests without calling google and I do not want to mock that...

That means I have to do an entry in the

```
requirejs.config(
  {
  async: 'lib/async',
  googlemaps:'async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'
});
```

and in my Viewmodel I use this instead:

```
define(['googlemaps'], function(){

//Google maps is **NOT** available

}
```

but google object is undefined.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Is nobody doing unit test here where google maps is incjected  as module? Can`t belive that...